# Retrieve and check a back end call

Tags: php, request, echo

I'm somewhat new to PHP.  I'm trying to add to a script to confirm data in a http call to our server.  The clients back end makes a call to a script on our server called sample.php which contains data from the client.  In this call the client also passes confirmation data (FX=yyy) and we respond.

The clients backends call contains, for example:

```
?token=xxx&FX=yyy
```

Our script:

```
<?php 
$token=$_REQUEST["token"];
$msg = "zz1=5&zz2=&token=$token";

{ echo("$msg"); } 
?>
```

Our script works fine.  data is received and returned without a issue.  I want to first confirm that FX = yyy before $msg is returned.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$token=$_REQUEST["token"];
if($_REQUEST["FX"]=="yyy"){
  $msg = "zz1=5&zz2=&token=$token";
  echo $msg; 
}
?>
```

you should take some things into consideration though:

- will this script be called only via GET (your backend call example suggests it will) then why not use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST
- depending on what your script does you might want to add some validation of user input (to prevent things like mysql injection)
- this is basic PHP code / basic programming, you should definitely check [the manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: Hi diesonne.  Yes.  It is called by GET.  FX does contain the validation.